# Group based on a field in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Assume I have database structure as;

```
[
    {name: "alex" , surname: "brown" , school: "washington"},
    {name: "felix" , surname: "yellow" , school: "georgia"},
    {name: "felix" , surname: "yellow" , school: "georgia"},
    {name: "tommy" , surname: "brown" , school: "davis"},
    {name: "tommy" , surname: "brown" , school: "davis"},
    {name: "tommy" , surname: "brown" , school: "davis"},
    {name: "tommy" , surname: "brown" , school: "davis"}
]
```

What I want to do is group them by their school info.
So expected result is;

```
{
    school: davis
    students: [
        {name: "tommy" , surname: "brown"},
        {name: "tommy" , surname: "brown"},
        {name: "tommy" , surname: "brown"},
        {name: "tommy" , surname: "brown"},
    ]

},
{
    school: georgia
    students: [
        {name: "felix" , surname: "yellow"}
    ]

},
{
    school: washington
    students: [
        {name: "alex" , surname: "brown"}
    ]

}
```

To be able to this I think about using `$group` as;

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$group: {"_id" : "$school", name : "$name" , surname: "$surname"}}
])
```

But I think, I misunderstood the `$group`. So how can I wrote this query?

Comment: Look at [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/) in the documentation

Comment: Thank you I achieve it by using document; https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do following :

```
db.your_collection.aggregate([
    { $group : {
            _id : '$school',
            'students' : { 
                $push: { name : '$name', surname : '$surname'
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: this what I have done after checking the document. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

When using `$group`, the fields beyond `_id` must be defined using [accumulator operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/#accumulators). In this case you want to use `$push` because for each unique `school` you want to assemble an array of students:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$group: {
        "_id" : "$school", 
        students: {$push: { name : "$name" , surname: "$surname"}}
    }}
])
```

Comment: this what I have done after checking the document. Thank you.